# is it possible to get file local system path in file upload using java?

Tags: java

I have the problem with file upload to dropbox. I want to get original file path of local system.

But it is the restriction of browser we can get fake path. So, is it possible to get original path of file ?`

Comment: How do you upload the file?

Comment: Not entirely sure but since it would be security issue I would say it's not possible.

Comment: I'm doubt about you don't know the local file path when you upload that file to dropbox. Do you really want to get the file path which is know by you?

Comment: @Fumu7: My understanding is, that you as a user are uploading file from your own disk e.g. `c:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\myTextFile.txt`. The question is whether you can find out location from where the file was uploaded. So you want to find out in your java program that the file was uploaded from `c:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\myTextFile.txt`.

Comment: Can i ask why you need the path? It serves little purpose...

Answer (score 0):

On recent browsers this is not possible due to security restrictions. There is no need for web applications to know about locale file system, thus browsers only send the actual path. In older browsers (i.e. IE 6) it was possible to determine the local file path, but from a user perspective you actually don't want any web server to know your locale structures.